# Migirating to Stimulsoft Core

Tags: asp.net-core, stimulsoft

For getting Pdf report in Asp.net MVC I am working with Stimulsoft 2015. The problem is that I have no idea how to convert my code in order to work with Stimulsoft Core in Asp.net Core. it seems some features are not available anymore in Stimulsoft Core (like StiReport). 
This is the code which works fine in Asp.net MVC

```
    public ActionResult GetReportSnapshot(string sort)
    {

        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Jobs.mrt"));

        report["@PrjectId"] = 1;
        report["@OrderBy"] = sort;
        report.Dictionary.Variables["title"] = new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiVariable("title", sort);

        report.Render();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        FileStreamResult fsr = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
        return fsr;
    }
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

In NuGet Package `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore` version `2018.3.5`.
and `Asp.Net core 2.0`.

This is working for me, Try this:

```
public IActionResult GetReportSnapshot(string sort)
        {

            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.Load(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\report.mrt"); // laod report
            report.Render();

            report["@PrjectId"] = 1;
            report["@OrderBy"] = sort;
            report.Dictionary.Variables["title"] = new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiVariable("title", sort);


            // Create an PDF settings instance. You can change export settings.
            var settings = new Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportSettings();
            // Create an PDF service instance.
            var service = new Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportService();

            // Create a MemoryStream object.
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            // Export PDF using MemoryStream.
            service.ExportTo(report, stream, settings);

            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What nuget packages are you using? It could be you are missing the nuget packages containing the `StiReport` class. (I see they split up their library over multiple nuget packages)

Also it could be they have not migrated this part to dotnet core yet. 
i'd advise you to click around there github repo and see if you can find any information there: https://github.com/stimulsoft, or on there website.

By the looks of nuget they have only recently started to migrate to dotnet core so this would suppose my second suggestion is the right suggestion.
[image]

Comment: I'm using stimulsoft core nuget package, and there is only one package for .net core in nuget package manager. I thought they have done with core version  but it seems they are still working on it